# Angular web components are not applying global styles when bundled and hooked in angular project

Tags: angular, sass, web-component

Using ng single bundle to bundle the angular component as a web component in one js file and then mounting  these web component to  angular project. But while mounting the global css of the web components that is **style.scss** are not getting reflected.

Thanks  in advance for help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

certainly can keep things simply by having one global `styles.scss` SCSS file, and you can also use styling on a component-by-component basis.

I like to keep my styles as global as possible avoiding component styling as I find that things can get very messy very quickly, especially when working on teams with multiple developers.

Having global styles keeps everyone using the same structure and system, and encourages discussions about patterns and use cases.

**SCSS Folder Structure**
Once you have your Angular project ready and set up to use SCSS, it's time to move some things around.

To get things started:

Create a folder in your `src` project folder called styles.
Move your `styles.scss` file into the newly created styles folder.
Update your `angular.json` file to point to the new location of your `styles.scss` file.